# How to handle implicitly passed futures in play views

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, playframework-2.4

In my particular case I have a menu that is rendered on all pages. The menu content is loaded from a database using slick and passed implicitly to the view. The whole thing looks like this:

**Controller**

```
class Application @Inject()(
  implicit val menuContext: MenuContext
) extends Controller {

  def index = Action.async {
    val content: Future[Content] = getContent
    content.map(c => Ok(views.html.index(c)))
  } 
}
```

**MenuContext**

```
class MenuContext {
  val models: Future[List[SomeModel]] = getModelsFromDB
}
```

**View**

```
@(content: Content)(implicit menuContext: MenuContext)
...
@menuContext.models // how to access my actual model and not the Future?
...
```

How do I access `List[SomeModel]` in my view? Is there an `Action.async` equivalent in play for passing implicit parameters? Or is there maybe even a better solution for stuff that is required in (almost) all views?

Comment: Future execution is definitely a task for back-end and not for a template. You should pass the actual model to the view.

Comment: Excuse my noobish question, but how do I do that in a non-blocking way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I'm adding another answer here, to specifically try to [DRY up](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) the injection of menus into your Actions.

The principal problem is that you need to inject the menus at *just the right time*, namely:

- When you have the data ready (or at least a `Future` holding the data)
- When you know which template is going to be rendered
- When you know what status code you'll be returning

Because of these constraints, we can't use an [`ActionBuilder`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder) or [`ActionRefiner`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.ActionRefiner) - they assume that your inner block of controller code will produce a finished `Result`.

So instead, we'll define a trait we can mix into our controllers:

```
trait MenuDecoration {

  def withMenuSimple(body: Future[List[SomeModel] => Result]):Future[Result] = {
    val fm = getModelsFromDB
    val fb = body
    for {
      m <- fm
      b <- fb
    } yield(b(m))
  }
}
```

This should look pretty familiar from my other answer, and it works the same way - it will start the execution of both async tasks, bringing them together once they are both done.

An `Action` that needs to decorate the template with a menu looks like this:

```
class BlahController extends Controller with MenuDecoration {

  def index = Action.async {
    withMenuSimple {
      getContent.map { content => implicit menu =>
        Ok(views.html.index(content))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why `withMenuSimple` ? Because at some point you'll probably want to examine the `Request` - so we have this alternative:

```
trait MenuDecoration {
   ...

  def withMenu(body: RequestHeader => Future[List[SomeModel] => Result])(implicit request:RequestHeader):Future[Result] = {
    val fm = fMenus
    val fb = body(request)
    for {
      m <- fm
      b <- fb
    } yield(b(m))
  }
}
```

which you'd use like this:

```
def indexWithReq = Action.async { implicit request =>
  withMenu { req =>
    getContent.map { content => implicit menu =>
      Ok(views.html.index(content))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did learn quite some things today. Have my upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely not a good idea to make a template have to deal with a `Future` - so the question becomes the one in your comment - how to **non-blockingly** (?) get the content from your async content source, **as well as** your menu items from your other async content source?

A `for`-comprehension on the two `Future` instances does the trick:

```
def index = Action.async { 
  val fContent:Future[Content] = getContent
  val fMenus:Future[List[SomeModel] = getModelsFromDB

  for {
    content <- fContent
    menus <- fMenus
  } yield(Ok(views.html.index(content)(menus))))
}
```

*Note*: You may be tempted to try and save a few lines and put the method calls (`getContent`, `getModelsFromDB`) straight into the `for` block.
Unfortunately, while it'll compile *and* work, the two tasks **won't** run in parallel, thereby making the exercise somewhat futile.

Comment: Thank you millhouse. The point of passing menuContext implicitly is because I want to avoid to fetch the menu entries in every action by hand. `menuContext` is something that should be available in almost all views. Ideally I inject a menuContext in a controller and let scala implicits do the magic.